# Calling a Sub & Number

Tags: vba, subroutine

Afternoon All,

I have a list of subs for example (I will actually have 5 in total),

```
Sub Office1()
Does a thing
End Sub
Sub Office2()
Does a slightly different thing
End Sub
```

I also have a calculation that leaves lvl = a number between 1 and 5

```
lvl = 1 '(or 2,3,4,5)
```

So when I want to call Office1-5 it will depend on a lvl, so what I am looking to do is:

```
Call "Office" & lvl
```

I struggled searching this one out as I wasn't sure how to phrase the question.

Hope you can help,

Cheers,

Bill

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: include your "level" as an argument, then handle

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub office1()
    MsgBox 1
End Sub

Sub office2()
    MsgBox 2
End Sub

Sub office3()
    MsgBox 3
End Sub

Sub main()
    For lvl = 1 To 3
        Application.Run "office" & lvl
    Next lvl
End Sub
```

Comment: If you get the error "Cannot run the macro 'office1'. The macro may not be available..." Then you should include the module name in the string like `"Module1.office" & lvl`

Comment: Perfect thank you; Application.Run "office" & lvl     is exactly what I needed.